Find the join of two set partitions
Two partitions of a set have a greatest lower bound (meet) and a least upper bound (join).
See here: Meets and joins in the lattice of partitions (Math SE)
The meet is easy to calculate. I am trying to improve the calculation of the join.
As part of a library I have written a class for set partitions.
Its join method can be found here.
It uses the method pairs, which can be found here.
Creating all the 2-subsets of a block is not a great idea for big blocks.
I intended this approach only as a prototype.
But to my surprise I was still faster than my Python interpretation of the answer on Math SE.
The SetPart is essentially the list of blocks wrapped in a class.
This is the property pairs:    (file)
from itertools import combinations


def pairs(self):

    result = set()

    for block in self.blocks:
        for pair in combinations(block, 2):
            result.add(pair)

    return result

The method join_pairs is the essential part of the algorithm.:    (file)
The method merge_pair merges two elements into the same block.
def join_pairs(self, other):

    from discretehelpers.set_part import SetPart

    result = SetPart([], self.domain)

    for pair in self.pairs.union(other.pairs):
        result.merge_pair(*pair)

    return result

The method join uses join_pairs. It removes redundant elements (called trash) from the blocks of both partitions. This trash is then added to the blocks of the result again. This way only the necessary amount of 2-element subsets is used in the calculation.
def join(self, other):

    from itertools import chain
    from discretehelpers.set_part import SetPart

    meet_part = self.meet(other)

    trash = set()
    rep_to_trash = dict()
    for block in meet_part.blocks:
        block_rep = min(block)
        block_trash = set(block) - {block_rep}
        trash |= block_trash
        rep_to_trash[block_rep] = block_trash

    clean_s_blocks = [sorted(set(block) - trash) for block in self.blocks]
    clean_o_blocks = [sorted(set(block) - trash) for block in other.blocks]

    clean_s_part = SetPart(clean_s_blocks)
    clean_o_part = SetPart(clean_o_blocks)

    clean_join_part = clean_s_part.join_pairs(clean_o_part)

    s_elements = set(chain.from_iterable(self.blocks))
    o_elements = set(chain.from_iterable(other.blocks))
    dirty_domain = s_elements | o_elements
    clean_domain = dirty_domain - trash

    dirty_join_blocks = []
    clean_blocks_with_singletons = clean_join_part.blocks_with_singletons(elements=clean_domain)
    for clean_block in clean_blocks_with_singletons:
        dirty_block = set(clean_block)
        for element in clean_block:
            if element in rep_to_trash:
                dirty_block |= rep_to_trash[element]
        dirty_join_blocks.append(sorted(dirty_block))

    return SetPart(dirty_join_blocks, domain=self.domain)

My standard example are these two partitions:
a = SetPart([[0, 1, 2, 4], [5, 6, 9], [7, 8]])
b = SetPart([[0, 1], [2, 3, 4], [6, 8, 9]])

To test performance I have increased their size by factor 10, e.g. by replacing 5 with 50...59:
import timeit

from discretehelpers.set_part import SetPart


a = SetPart([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49], [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99], [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89]])
b = SetPart([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49], [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]])

print(timeit.timeit(lambda: a.meet(b), number=1000))        # 0.03588864533230662
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: a.meet_pairs(b), number=1000))  # 1.766225082334131
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: a.join(b), number=1000))        # 0.7479327972978354
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: a.join_pairs(b), number=1000))  # 4.01305090310052

My question is mainly about improving the algorithm.
But fancy Python tricks are also welcome.
I have edited the question. By removing redundant elements before the calculation, I have avoided choking the process with factorial growth. But this is probably still far from the optimal solution.
A simplified version of the SetPart class can be found here.
It can be run in a single Python file, and has no dependencies.
As requested, here is the whole class, including the methods shown above:
from functools import cached_property
from itertools import combinations, product, chain
 
 
def have(val):
    return val is not None
 
 
########################################################################################################################
 
 
class SetPart(object):
 
    def __init__(self, blocks=None, domain='N'):
 
        """
        :param blocks: List of lists. Each block is a list with at least two elements. The blocks do not intersect.
        :param domain: Set of allowed elements of blocks. Can be a finite set. Elements are usually integers.
                       By default, the domain is the set of non-negative integers.
        """
 
        if domain not in ['N', 'Z']:
            assert type(domain) in [set, list, tuple, range]
            self.domain = set(domain)
        else:
            self.domain = domain  # keep the letters
 
        if blocks is None:
            self.set_trivial()
            return
 
        blocks = sorted(sorted(block) for block in blocks if len(block) > 1)
        if not blocks:
            self.set_trivial()
            return
 
        self.blocks = blocks
 
        _ = dict()
        for block_index, block in enumerate(self.blocks):
            for element in block:
                _[element] = block_index
        self.non_singleton_to_block_index = _
 
        self.non_singletons = set(self.non_singleton_to_block_index.keys())
        assert len(self.non_singletons) == sum([len(block) for block in self.blocks])
 
        if self.domain == 'N':
            self.length = max(self.non_singletons) + 1
 
        self.trivial = False
 
    ##############################################################################################
 
    def set_trivial(self):
        self.trivial = True
        self.blocks = []
        self.non_singleton_to_block_index = dict()
        self.non_singletons = set()
 
        if self.domain == 'N':
            self.length = 0
 
    ###############################################
 
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.blocks == other.blocks
 
    ###############################################
 
    def element_in_domain(self, element):
        if self.domain == 'N':
            return type(element) == int and element >= 0
        elif self.domain == 'Z':
            return type(element) == int
        else:
            return element in self.domain
 
    ###############################################
 
    def merge_pair(self, a, b):
 
        """
        When elements `a` and `b` are in different blocks, both blocks will be merged.
        Changes the partition. Returns nothing.
        """
 
        if a == b:
            return  # nothing to do
 
        assert self.element_in_domain(a) and self.element_in_domain(b)
 
        a_found = a in self.non_singletons
        b_found = b in self.non_singletons
 
        if a_found and b_found:
 
            block_index_a = self.non_singleton_to_block_index[a]
            block_index_b = self.non_singleton_to_block_index[b]
 
            if block_index_a == block_index_b:
                return  # nothing to do
 
            block_a = self.blocks[block_index_a]
            block_b = self.blocks[block_index_b]
            merged_block = sorted(block_a + block_b)
 
            self.blocks.remove(block_a)
            self.blocks.remove(block_b)
            self.blocks.append(merged_block)
 
        elif not a_found and not b_found:
            self.blocks.append([a, b])
 
        else:  # a_found and not b_found
            if b_found and not a_found:
                a, b = b, a
            block_index_a = self.non_singleton_to_block_index[a]
            self.blocks[block_index_a].append(b)
 
        self.__init__(self.blocks, self.domain)  # reinitialize
 
    ###############################################
 
    def blocks_with_singletons(self, elements=None):
        """
        :param elements: Any subset of the domain.
        :return: Blocks with added singleton-blocks for each element in `elements` that is not in an actual block.
        """
        assert type(elements) in [set, list, range]
        assert self.non_singletons.issubset(set(elements))
        singletons = set(elements).difference(self.non_singletons)
        singleton_blocks = [[_] for _ in singletons]
        return sorted(self.blocks + singleton_blocks)
 
    ##############################################################################################
 
    @cached_property
    def pairs(self):
        """
        :return: For each block the set of all is 2-element subsets. All those in one set.
        Slow for big blocks, because of factorial growth.
        """
        result = set()
        for block in self.blocks:
            for pair in combinations(block, 2):
                result.add(pair)
        return result
 
    ###############################################
 
    def join_pairs(self, other):
        """
        :param other: another set partition
        :return: The join of the two set partitions.
        This method uses the property `pairs`, so it is also slow for big blocks.
        """
        assert self.domain == other.domain
        result = SetPart([], self.domain)
        for pair in self.pairs.union(other.pairs):
            result.merge_pair(*pair)
        return result
 
    ###############################################
 
    def meet(self, other):
        """
        :param other: another set partition
        :return: The meet of the two set partitions.
        Let M be the meet of partitions A and B. The blocks of M are the intersections of the blocks of A and B.
        """
        meet_blocks = []
        for s_block, o_block in product(self.blocks, other.blocks):
            intersection = set(s_block) & set(o_block)
            if intersection:
                meet_blocks.append(sorted(intersection))
        return SetPart(meet_blocks, self.domain)
 
    ###############################################
 
    def join(self, other):
        """
        :param other: another set partition
        :return: The join of the two set partitions.
        This method uses the method `join_pairs`.
        The danger of factorial growth is reduced, by making the input partitions smaller.
        """
        meet_part = self.meet(other)
 
        trash = set()
        rep_to_trash = dict()
        for block in meet_part.blocks:
            block_rep = min(block)
            block_trash = set(block) - {block_rep}
            trash |= block_trash
            rep_to_trash[block_rep] = block_trash
 
        clean_s_blocks = [sorted(set(block) - trash) for block in self.blocks]
        clean_o_blocks = [sorted(set(block) - trash) for block in other.blocks]
 
        clean_s_part = SetPart(clean_s_blocks)
        clean_o_part = SetPart(clean_o_blocks)
 
        clean_join_part = clean_s_part.join_pairs(clean_o_part)
 
        s_elements = set(chain.from_iterable(self.blocks))
        o_elements = set(chain.from_iterable(other.blocks))
        dirty_domain = s_elements | o_elements
        clean_domain = dirty_domain - trash
 
        dirty_join_blocks = []
        clean_blocks_with_singletons = clean_join_part.blocks_with_singletons(elements=clean_domain)
        for clean_block in clean_blocks_with_singletons:
            dirty_block = set(clean_block)
            for element in clean_block:
                if element in rep_to_trash:
                    dirty_block |= rep_to_trash[element]
            dirty_join_blocks.append(sorted(dirty_block))
 
        return SetPart(dirty_join_blocks, domain=self.domain)


I can't say much on the algorithm atm, but I think the if len(pairs) > 0: check is redundant and can be safely removed. Also have you tried using a different interpreter than the standard CPython interpreter like pypy to see if there is any performance boost from that?

What is a block? In SetPart([[0, 1], [2, 3, 4], [6, 8, 9]]), I do not see 5. Replacing a single number by appending 0..9 should increase size by 9. I may have found en.wikiversity on Discrete helpers - it is miles from the source code, which does not follow PEPs 8&257 regarding documentation.

@Dair Indeed, I removed it. I really just want to improve the program. (I did not really mean "fancy Python tricks". Actually I was thinking of generators.) @greybeard A set is partitioned into blocks. E.g. [5, 6, 9] is a block of partition a. It does contain the element 5. I meant increase by factor 10.

I have done that with the simplified class linked at the end of the question. (I suppose no-one expects me to paste 200 lines of code on this page.) Divorcing the code from the class is not really possible. join uses meet and join_pairs, and that uses pairs and merge_pair. But the rest of the class can be ignored. The question is only about the join method.

Done. If huge blocks of code are to be expected on this page, maybe it should introduce subpages. Or at least collapsible boxes.

(subpages[/]collapsible boxes a folding viewer, or at least "splitable"? Search on CR.meta.)

Please do not modify the code or add different versions once answers start coming in. If you have new code you want reviewed, post a follow-up question instead. Please see what you may and may not do after receiving answers.

This is an attempt to build the same functionality. I didn't read all of your code, but tried to implement the algorithm you linked to on Math StackExchange.
I suspect you can do it even faster for large sets if you use pandas.
class FastSetPartition:
    '''Set partition with similar interface to SetPar'''

    def __init__(self, blocks):
        """
        :param blocks: List of lists. Each block is a list with at least two elements. The blocks do not intersect.

        A block with a single element is named a singleton. Singletons are not stored.
        """
        self.blocks = frozenset([frozenset(block) for block in blocks])

    def join(self, other):
        """
        :param self:  One set partition
        :param other: Another set partition
        :return: The join of the two set partitions.
        """
        # Find the domain relevant for the join. 
        dm_self = frozenset([x for block in self.blocks for x in block])
        dm_other = frozenset([x for block in other.blocks for x in block])
        dm = dm_self | dm_other

        # For each element in the domain, register which block it is part of. Assign an index to each block
        self_block_list = [block for block in self.blocks]
        x2self_no = {x: block_no for block_no, block in enumerate(self_block_list) for x in block}
        other_block_list = [block for block in other.blocks]
        x2other_no = {x: block_no for block_no, block in enumerate(other_block_list) for x in block}
        join_block_list = []
        x2join_no = {}

        # We build the join-blocks one block at a time
        # The one we are currently working on is called current_block
        # The latest addition is called new_elements
        current_block = set()
        new_elements = set()
        
        def new_block(x):
            '''Begin building a new join-block'''
            nonlocal current_block
            nonlocal new_elements
            # It is important that current_block starts out empty.
            # This way we add blocks from both self and other.
            current_block = set([])
            new_elements = set([x])

        def join_blocks(block_list, x2block_no):
            '''Expand the current block with the given partition'''
            nonlocal current_block
            nonlocal new_elements
            # Expand only new elements via the block_list
            added_elements = set()
            added_blocks = set()
            for x in new_elements:
                if x in x2block_no:
                    added_blocks.add(x2block_no[x])
                else: # x is a singleton in the current partition
                    added_elements.add(x)
            for block_no in added_blocks:
                added_elements |= block_list[block_no]
            # Grow current block
            new_elements = added_elements - current_block
            current_block |= added_elements
            return len(new_elements)
        
        def close_block():
            '''Add the current block to the join result'''
            join_block_no = len(join_block_list)
            for x in current_block:
                x2join_no[x] = join_block_no
            join_block_list.append(current_block)

        def join_self_blocks():
            return join_blocks(self_block_list, x2self_no)
        def join_other_blocks():
            return join_blocks(other_block_list, x2other_no)


        for x in dm:
            if x in x2join_no:
                continue
            new_block(x)
            while join_self_blocks() + join_other_blocks() > 0:
                pass
            close_block()


Thanks for the algorithm. It works better than mine. My rewrite is shown as a separate answer, and I have added it to the library. Developers rarely say nice things about nonlocal. (See e.g. this answer to my other question on this page.) So someone may still find ways to improve the code. (But probably not me.)

This is my rewritten version of the solution by Peer Sommerlund:    (file)
def join_fast(self, other):

    from discretehelpers.set_part import SetPart

    domain = self.non_singletons | other.non_singletons

    result_blocks = []
    result_dict = {}

    # We build the join-blocks one block at a time.
    # The one we are currently working on is called `current_block`.
    # The latest addition is called `new_elements`.
    current_block = set()
    new_elements = set()

    def new_block(e):
        """begin building a new join-block"""
        nonlocal current_block
        nonlocal new_elements
        # It is important that current_block starts out empty.
        # This way we add blocks from both self and other.
        current_block = set([])
        new_elements = set([e])

    def join_blocks(part):
        """expand the current block with the given partition"""
        nonlocal current_block
        nonlocal new_elements

        part_dict = part.non_singleton_to_block_index

        # expand only new elements via the block_list
        added_elements = set()
        added_blocks = set()
        for e in new_elements:
            if e in part_dict:
                added_blocks.add(part_dict[e])
            else:  # `e` is a singleton in the current partition
                added_elements.add(e)
        for block_index in added_blocks:
            added_elements |= set(part.blocks[block_index])
        # grow current block
        new_elements = added_elements - current_block
        current_block |= added_elements
        return len(new_elements)

    def close_block():
        """add the current block to the join result"""
        join_block_index = len(result_blocks)
        for e in current_block:
            result_dict[e] = join_block_index
        result_blocks.append(current_block)

    for element in domain:
        if element in result_dict:
            continue
        new_block(element)
        while join_blocks(self) + join_blocks(other) > 0:
            pass
        close_block()

    return SetPart(result_blocks)
    

For the big example partitions it is 12 times faster than my improved method join_pairs.
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: a.join_slow(b), number=1000))  # 0.8285696366801858
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: a.join_fast(b), number=1000))  # 0.06911674793809652

